# How to fix handleChange method to output user's input into desired result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two fields called latitude and longitude

```
<TextBoxField
  id="location-latitude-control"
  title="Required: Latitude"
  name="location.latitude"
  value={location.latitude}
  handleChange={this.handleChange}
  handleBlur={this.handleBlur}
/>

<TextBoxField
  id="location-longitude-control"
  title="Required: longitude"
  name="location.longitude"
  value={location.longitude}
  handleChange={this.handleChange}
  handleBlur={this.handleBlur}
/>
```

For **latitude**, I need the desired output to be in the format of `XX.xxxxxx` by adding leading and trailing zeros based on the data

For **longitude**, I need the desired output to be in the format of `XXX.xxxxxx` by adding leading and trailing zeros based on the data

How can I fix my `handleChange` method to properly format user's input:

```
handleChange = e => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    return Math.sign(val) === -1
    ? Math.abs(val) > 10
    ? "-" + Math.abs(val).toFixed(6)
    : "-0" + Math.abs(val).toFixed(6)
    : Math.abs(val) > 10
    ? Math.abs(val).toFixed(6)
    : "0" + Math.abs(val).toFixed(6);
}
```

**Expected behavior for latitude:**

```
".12" should convert it to "00.120000"
"-1.1", should allow to input "-01.100000"
"-1.23", should allow to input "-01.230000"
"-30", should allow to input "-30.000000"
"12.25", should allow to input "12.25000"
"7.0", should allow to input "07.000000"
"12", should allow to input "12.000000"
```

**Expected behavior for longitude:**

```
".12" should convert it to "000.120000"
"-1.1", should allow to input "-001.100000"
"-1.23", should allow to input "-001.230000"
"-30", should allow to input "-030.000000"
"12.25", should allow to input "012.25000"
"7.0", should allow to input "007.000000"
"12", should allow to input "012.000000"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two functions to handle both latitude and longitude.

```js
handleLatitudeChange = e => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    const valSign = Math.sign(val);
    val = Math.abs(val).toFixed(6);
    if(Math.abs(val) < 10)  val = `0${val}`;
    if(valSign === -1)  val = `-${val}`;
    return val;
}
handleLongitudeChange = e => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    const valSign = Math.sign(val);
    val = Math.abs(val).toFixed(6);
    if(Math.abs(val) < 10)  val = `00${val}`;
    else if(Math.abs(val) < 100)    val = `0${val}`;
    if(valSign === -1)  val = `-${val}`;
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ankit, your solution also works great. Latitude one looks good! I created another function for longitude similar to the one you provided above for latitude. All scenarios looks good except when I enter `12` for longitude, it converts the data into `12.000000` instead of `012.000000`. Any idea what can I do to fix that?

Comment: Thank you so much for providing both methods! It really helps a lot and I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mapNumber` function to format your data.

First parameter is the number you want to format, second parameter is a number of leading zeros to be added and third parameter is a number of trailing zeros to be added.

```js
function mapNumber(num, leading, trailing) {
  var s = num.toFixed(trailing) + "";
  while (s.length <= leading + trailing) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
}

console.log('Latitude: ', mapNumber(3.2458, 2, 6));
console.log('Longtitude: ', mapNumber(11.764, 3, 6));
```

Comment: Thank you so much David for your response. Your solution works like a charm, except for one issue. When I enter `-1.1` for latitude I see that it converts into `-1.100000` instead of `-01.100000`. In such case, how can I fix that?